# CakePHP login function for ajax call

Tags: cakephp

So here is situation:

I'm using Js helper to create ajax login form in CakePHP and this is placed in my view:

```
<?php 
$data = $this->Js->get('#UserLoginForm')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));
      $this->Js->get('#UserLoginForm')->event(
        'submit',
        $this->Js->request(
          array ('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
          array (
                  'update' => '#messagediv',
                  'before' => '$("#loading").fadeIn()',
                  'complete' => '$("#loading").fadeOut()',
                  'data' => $data,
                  'async' => true,    
                  'dataExpression'=>true,
                  'method' => 'POST',
                )
          )
      );
?>
```

Then below this I have my form included and below form I have:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('submit);
?>


<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>
```

Now I don't know how to make proper function in controller to check for login and redirect if successfull or display error if not..

I was able to make something that check for login and echo 1 if login deatils are correct and echo 0 if not but whenever I try to use redirect in controller function it just load "whole login page" in div #messagediv...

This is how my controller action looks now:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->isAjax()) {
      $this->layout = 'ajax';

      if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Login Successfull');
      } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Login Incorrect');
      }

    }
  }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

So how to redirect after login successfull and how to output error message to #messagediv if wrong username or pw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do (load only the flash message and not the whole page), change your action like this:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->isAjax()) {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login Successfull');
            $this->redirect('wherever');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login Incorrect');
            $this->render('messagediv');
        }    
    }
}
```

Then create a View at View/Users/messagediv.ctp that only contains `echo $this->Session->flash();`

There might be other ways of doing this that might be better, though I'm not sure depending on your exact use for it. This should solve what you're trying to do (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: This worked but actually I have another question, I used different method using json_encode from php $response = result and other, then proceed it to view and in view at ajax success part depending on result returned I use redirect and other stuffs.. can you tell me is it good/safe way for doing such thing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly, it probably depends on how you implemented it. You should probably make a new question to ask that - might be able to answer if I can see the code you're using.

Comment: After seeing your edit, I think I understand more. Yeah, that should be an okay way of doing it :)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot I marked it as usefull as it helped me... Basically I still use $this->Auth->login() { here json_encode for positive login } else { here json_encode for negative answer } and I proceed it to view file... Then in view file I parse json and in success part of ajax success: - based on answer from controller I fade in error message or if logged I redirect user to dashboard... It's working perfectly but was just asking is it safe and as I understand as it should be as it's still using cakephp component auth for login.. Thanks once more!

Comment: Well yes that's still safe (as long as you're using Cake's auth component to deny access to your protected pages for non-logged in users). However, it's not really the 'cake' way of doing things. Personally I'd suggest doing it the way you originally asked about, but this JSON way is acceptable I suppose if that's how you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding RequestHandler to your $components array.

```
var $components = array("RequestHandler");
```